# Tic Tac Toe issue

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to figure out why playing the tic tac toe game works fine until it needs to pick a winner vertically. I only do the first left side right and the other sides it ignores. Below is the function I used to make the game know a winner if all conditions are met.

```py
def check_winner():

    for row in range(3):
        if buttons[row][0]['text'] == buttons[row][1]['text'] == buttons[row][2]['text'] != "":
            buttons[row][0].config(bg="green")
            buttons[row][1].config(bg="green")
            buttons[row][2].config(bg="green")
            return True

    for column in range(3):
        if buttons[0][column]['text'] == buttons[1][column]['text'] == buttons[2][column]['text'] != "":
            buttons[0][column].config(bg="green")
            buttons[1][column].config(bg="green")
            buttons[2][column].config(bg="green")
            return True


        if buttons[0][0]['text'] == buttons[1][1]['text'] == buttons[2][2]['text'] != "":
            buttons[0][0].config(bg="green")
            buttons[1][1].config(bg="green")
            buttons[2][2].config(bg="green")
            return True

        elif buttons[0][2]['text'] == buttons[1][1]['text'] == buttons[2][0]['text'] != "":

            buttons[0][2].config(bg="green")
            buttons[1][1].config(bg="green")
            buttons[2][0].config(bg="green")
            return True

        elif empty_spaces() is False:
            for row in range(3):
                for column in range(3):
                    buttons[row][column].config(bg='yellow')
            return "Tie"
        else:
            return False
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is hard to see what is happening. The issue seems likely to be with code that you haven't shown. Also -- the logic seems convoluted, using the visual display itself as the main data structure, rather than maintaining an internal board data structure which is merely displayed by the GUI. Such an approach makes it hard to separate the logic of the game from the logic of the display.

Comment: I agree with @JohnColeman. It seems that your conditions should work, so it's probably some issue with `buttons`. Can you share the code for `buttons`?

Comment: You may want to move the code starting from the second `if` statement in the second `for` loop (3rd `if` statement) and below _outside_ the second `for` loop. You are checking the diagonals three times, which is unnecessary.

Comment: The diagonal checks shouldn't be inside the `for column` loop.

Comment: It never gets to the second column, because you return in all the other `if/elif` blocks in the column loop.

Comment: Just remove one level of indentation from everything starting from the first diagonal check.